# What is this blue stone powering White Vision?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

In *WandaVision*, White Vision is introduced. This character is different from the Vision due to its colour, but also its (non-existent?) stone.

As you can see in the image below, the Vision is powered by the Mind Stone. However, White Vision has a blue space where the stone would be. We know that Steve Rogers replaced the Infinity Stones back to their original timelines, so this means that White Vision **cannot** have the Mind Stone. Therefore, what is this blue 'stone'?

[image]

Comment: I think it a lack of stone, showing the brain VISION

Comment: @Tloz apologies, but I don't really understand what you mean...

Comment: It was not specifically answered in the show and speculation is it's either exposed circuitry or leftover tesseract weaponry

Comment: @taylor.2317 Posting just before going to bed leads to this, sorry ^^.
I meant exactly what AnkitSharma said, the blue thing you see is inside VISION's head (what I called brain), and that there is no stone, just a hole

Comment: Definitely looks like an arc reactor, but I don't have any official confirmation for this.

Comment: I think they both have some kind of erzac of the stone, letting them emit energy like original. Both also had some bit of Wanda's power, but It's hard to say if it was contained there, or just its energy was channelled with it.

Comment: @Mithoron how did White Vision have a part of Wanda's power?

Comment: @taylor.2317 From the drone, that was imbued with Wanda's power when she dragged it out of Westview and threw it at Director Hayward's feet, and which in turn he (or rather his team) then used to power up White Vision (as seen in the Ep. 8 post credits scene).

Comment: @BMWurm why is this glow blue? Surely it would be red, like Wanda's magic?

Comment: I just answered the comment not the actual question: you asked where the power came from and it came from Wanda via the drone, and yes, as shown in the episode, the power is red, just like Wanda's magic. It powers up White Vision and the "stone" begins to glow as if a light has been switched on behind it - it's just dark beforehand (so it is very possible, like others have said, that it shows the "brain" behind or that it is just a facsimile of the "head laser" real Vision got from the mind stone).